# Idea 15/Android Studio 1.4 hangs on gradle sync for large projects

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We are working on an Android project (~50 modules) built over Gradle. We were able to successfully sync our project in IntelliJ Idea 14 (141.2735). CE (took around 30-60 seconds for gradle sync). With the release of IntelliJ Idea 15 CE(143.381)/Android Studio 1.4, we tried to migrate our project to the newer version, but we noticed that:

1. Gradle sync does not work for our project in IntelliJ Idea 15 or Android Studio 1.4. We tried this on both Ubuntu 14.04 and OsX El Captain.
2. When we try to perform gradle sync, the IDE freezes and becomes unresponsive indefinitely. The only way to get out of the IDE is to kill the corresponding process.
3. We tried increasing the heap space in 'vmoptions' to 4GB, but to no effect.

We have created a github repository with our project skeleton and gradle files (no source) which is hosted here: https://github.com/prateeksultania/android-gradle. In IntelliJ Idea 14, gradle sync works comfortably with the default vmoptions and completes in less than a minute. However, gradle sync for the same project takes forever on the newer IntelliJ Idea 15 or Android Studio 1.4. When we increase the max heap space size to 4 GB, gradle sync takes more than 3 minutes for this empty project, and even after that the IDE continues to occupy over 3 GB RAM. For our actual project with source and asset files the gradle sync never finishes on Idea 15 or Android Studio 1.4.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install both IntelliJ Idea 14(141.2735) and Android Studio 1.4, IntelliJ Idea 15(143.381) on your system(Either Ubuntu or Mac).
2. Clone this repository on your system: https://github.com/prateeksultania/android-gradle
3. Open IntelliJ Idea 14. Select Import > Project from Existing Sources > Use gradle as the build system.
4. Open the gradle tool window and click the refresh button (if gradle sync did not start automatically). Gradle sync will be performed which will take about a minute.
5. Open IntelliJ Idea 15 and import the project in the same way again.
6. Open the gradle tool window and click the refresh button (if gradle sync did not start automatically). Gradle sync fails to complete, IDE becomes unreponsive and consumes a lot of CPU.
7. Same happens for Android Studio 1.4

Could somebody please help us track this down?

Comment: could you please put log which will print in Messages Gradle Build while build gradle?

Comment: @Survivor: This happens during the gradle sync time. For this purpose, IDE logs are relevant, but are not helpful.

Comment: same here.. we have a similar list of dependencies ( on a local artifactory server ). if we manually turn off transitive dependencies sync goes fast, but of course then deps are missing. the new android studio in that setup is unusable. :(

Comment: @P.Melch: We have reported the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193616. We are hoping that someone from the core team will help us in resolving it. Meanwhile, you can try using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.5 CE and see if it helps. I will be grateful if you could let me know if it works.

Comment: intellij 14 helps actually, we've been using it for some days now.